# Are LJ6C outlets suitable for cat6 cabling or only cat5e / is there a different version for cat6 cabling?

Tags: cabling, layer1, standardisation

Are LJ6C suitable for cat6 cabling / is there a different version for cat6 cabling ?

I'm aware that you cant easily use an RJ45 cat5e jack for cat6 cable as the cable for cat6 is thicker, is this the case also for LJ6C outlets ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a cabling system to be certified at any category, you must use the same category for all the components in the system. Using Category-6 cabling with Category-5e parts is a waste of money since the cabling system can only be certified for Category-5e.

You may be able to find a manufacturer for these part in Category-6.

By the way, it is not an RJ-45 connector used in the cabling, it is an 8P8C connector.